# Need Help To Simplified Salesforce Formula Too Big to Execute

Tags: apex, formula

i need help to simplified my formula field.
i have requirement 1 formula field to count Achievement date from opportunity CloseDate based on my client requirement. it compiled too large(5123 character).
the formula is:

```
IF(
    OR(
        DAY(CloseDate) >= 26 && MONTH(CloseDate) = 1, 
        DAY(CloseDate) <= 25 && MONTH(CloseDate) = 2
    ), 
    DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 02, 01), 
    IF(
        OR(
            DAY(CloseDate) >= 26 && MONTH(CloseDate) = 2, 
            DAY(CloseDate) <= 25 && MONTH(CloseDate) = 3
        ), 
        DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 03, 01), 
        IF(
            OR(
                DAY(CloseDate) >= 26 && MONTH(CloseDate) = 3, 
                DAY(CloseDate) <= 25 && MONTH(CloseDate) = 4
            ), 
            DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 04, 01), 
            IF(
                OR(
                    DAY(CloseDate) >= 26 && MONTH(CloseDate) = 4, 
                    DAY(CloseDate) <= 25 && MONTH(CloseDate) = 5
                ), 
                DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 05, 01), 
                IF(
                    OR(
                        DAY(CloseDate) >= 26 && MONTH(CloseDate) = 5, 
                        DAY(CloseDate) <= 30 && MONTH(CloseDate) = 6
                    ),
                    DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 06, 01), 
                    IF(
                        OR(
                            DAY(CloseDate) >= 1 && MONTH(CloseDate) = 7, 
                            DAY(CloseDate) <= 25 && MONTH(CloseDate) = 7
                        ), 
                        DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 07, 01), 
                        IF(
                            OR(
                                DAY(CloseDate) >= 26 && MONTH(CloseDate) = 7, 
                                DAY(CloseDate) <= 25 && MONTH(CloseDate) = 8
                            ), 
                            DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 08, 01), 
                            IF(
                                OR(
                                    DAY(CloseDate) >= 26 && MONTH(CloseDate) = 8, 
                                    DAY(CloseDate) <= 25 && MONTH(CloseDate) = 9
                                ), 
                                DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 09, 01), 
                                IF(
                                    OR(
                                        DAY(CloseDate) >= 26 && MONTH(CloseDate) = 9, 
                                        DAY(CloseDate) <= 25 && MONTH(CloseDate) = 10
                                    ), 
                                    DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 10, 01), 
                                    IF(
                                        OR(
                                            DAY(CloseDate) >= 26 && MONTH(CloseDate) = 10, 
                                            DAY(CloseDate) <= 25 && MONTH(CloseDate) = 11
                                        ), 
                                        DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 11, 01), 
                                        IF(
                                            OR(
                                                DAY(CloseDate) >= 26 && MONTH(CloseDate) = 11, 
                                                DAY(CloseDate) <= 25 && MONTH(CloseDate) = 12
                                            ), 
                                            DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 12, 01), 
                                            IF(
                                                DAY(CloseDate) >= 26 && MONTH(CloseDate) = 12, 
                                                DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 03, 01), 
                                                CloseDate
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: I think the way to do this might be little sloppy create two hidden formula fields (these two formula fields will be a breakdown of your current formula) and create another formula field(third) to populate whichever (2 formula fields) is not empty.

Comment: Maybe you could put up your logic in english rather that the formula as it is really hard to dissect what you are trying to accomplish from a ton of nested IF statements

Comment: @Sanjay - Formula fields referencing other formula fields will take the combined compiled size and thus will not work either

Comment: Good to know ! @Eric

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_formula_size_tipsheet.pdf. This might help.

Comment: Looks like with the exception of months ending in June and July, you have a common `DAY(CloseDate) >= 26 && DAY(CloseDate) <= 25` you can use to try use to combine all the other periods.

Comment: Is `CloseDate` a formula field as well?

Comment: OP states this is Opportunity so `CloseDate` is not a formula; I agree with @Eric and also suggest you rewrite if possible using `CASE` as that compiles to far fewer characters than the repeated use of other functions

Comment: Is it just me, or is that first OR statement always going to be true?  All dates are either greater than Jan-26 or less than Feb-25.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok since this is just based on my interpretation of your formula, it might not be correct. But still wanted to give it a try.

Since most of your date comparisons range from 26th of one month to 25th of another, if we simply subtract 26 from Close Date, then the comparisons can be made by just looking at the month value.

 For rest of the conditions where the range differs from 26th to 25th, I have tried to add additional logic to take care of it.

```
CASE(
    MONTH(CloseDate - 26),
        1, DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 02, 01),
        2, DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 03, 01),
        3, DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 04, 01),
        4, DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 05, 01),
        5, DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 06, 01),
        6, DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), MONTH(CloseDate), 01),
        7, DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 08, 01),
        8, DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 09, 01),
        9, DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 10, 01),
        10, DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 11, 01),
        11, DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 12, 01),
        12, IF(MONTH(CloseDate) = 12, DATE(YEAR(CloseDate), 01, 01), CloseDate),
        CloseDate
)
```

Hopefully it makes sense!

Comment: @Kiunx, n.b. OOB field `FiscalYear` is same as `Year(CloseDate)` if your fiscal calendar is same as calendar quarter - this will save more formula compiled size characters

Comment: Many Thanks @AAU..
its working now. i put some Correction:
- MONTH(CloseDate - 25)
because start 26 achievement will be note for next month achievement.
- the last case 12. it should be:
12, IF(MONTH(CloseDate) = 12, DATE(YEAR(CloseDate)+1, 01, 01), CloseDate)
because achievement after 26th dec will be note as Achievement january next year

regards,
Willy